# Refresh Jquery Datatable after Row update

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC application. I'm now developing a search page that search users in database. This page contain a Partialview that display the search results as a Jquery datatable. 
Now, when I update a user, I want to reload/refresh the Jquery datatable with the new values.

**1. Code of the Ajax function that update a given user of the jquery datatable**

```
    function Update() {

    var res = validate();
    if (res == false) {
        return false;
    }
    var userObj = {
        Id: $('#userId').val(),
        Matricule: $('#userMatricule').val(),
        LastName: $('#userLastName').val(),
        FirstName: $('#userFirstName').val(),
        dateRecrutement: $('#userDateRecrutement').val(),
        entiteId: $('#entite').val(),
        roleId: $('#role').val(),
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/User/updateUserAjax',
        data: JSON.stringify(userObj),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            jQuery("#MessageUpdateUserConfirm").text(result);
            $("#dialog-confirm-update").dialog({
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Ok: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            ('#userId').val("");
            ('#userMatricule').val("");
            ('#userLastName').val("");
            ('#userFirstName').val("");
            ('#userDateRecrutement').val("");
            ('#entite').val("");
            ('#role').val("");
            location.reload();
            //let dt = $("#dataTables-userSearchResults").datatable();
            //dt.draw('full-reset');
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
    }
```

**2. Code of the main page that contain the search form & the partial view**

```
    <div class="row">
    <fieldset class="col-md-10" id="infoForm">           
        <form name="form-recherche" id="FormUsersSearch" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="matricule">Matricule</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">                        
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.matricule, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="nom"> Nom :</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">                        
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nom, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="prenom"> Prénom:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">                        
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.prenom, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="service">Direction:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.direction, ViewBag.DirectionId as SelectList, "---Select a Direction---", new { id = "Direction", @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="division">Division :</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">                        
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.division, ViewBag.division as SelectList, "---- Sélectionnez ----", new { id = "Division", @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="service">Service :</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">                        
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.service, ViewBag.service as SelectList, "---- Sélectionnez ----", new { id = "service", @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="dateRecrutementDebut">Date recrutement début :</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">                        
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dateRecrutementDebut, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker" } })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="dateRecrutementDebut">Date recrutement fin :</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">                        
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dateRecrutementFin, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker" } })
                </div>
            </div>            
        </form>
        <div class="b-right">
            <a class="btn btn-custom" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "User")'">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                Ajouter
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-custom"  id="searchUsers" >
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                Rechercher
            </a>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div id="usersearchResult">

    </div>
</div>
```

**3. The Jquery/AjaX function that feed the datatable**

```
    $(function () 
    {       
    var submitButton = $("#searchUsers");
     var infoForm = $("#infoForm");

            //  Attach event handler to submit button        
            submitButton.click(function () {            
                SubmitInfo(infoForm);            
            });        
        });

        function SubmitInfo(formContainer)
        {

            //event.preventDefault();        
            $.ajax({
                url: "@(Url.Action("UserSearch"))",
                type: "GET",
                data: formContainer.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    //Fill div with results               
                    $("#usersearchResult").html(data);
                },
                error: failedSearch
            });
        }

        function failedSearch() {
            $("usersearchResult").html = "There was a problem in the search. Please, try later on";


}
```

I tried the `$('#dataTables-userSearchResults').DataTable().ajax.reload()`, but it didn't work.

thanks for your help

Comment: **$('#dataTables-userSearchResults').DataTable().ajax.reload(),** what's happen by using this?

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing happen, I checked the navigator inspector for an eventual error, but nothing. total inactivity! Is there any solution for that problem ? thanks for your help!

Comment: Provide the code where you are initializing the jquery datatables and how are you filling data in datatables .

Comment: I provided the requested code. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Where are you initializing the dataTable plugin?  if you are and i am missing it, then i typically call table.ajax.reload(null, false); // false keeps the paging from resetting.

Comment: I don't see where you are doing this but if your ajax is a full html table that you are putting in the div, you will have to recreate the table.   You could set serverSide to true and use the ajax built into DataTables to populate your table

Comment: Thanks  WCEMSS, Actually i was initializing my JQ DT using a full table that i put on the div that contain my partialView.Now i'm updating all the JQ Datatable after the row update.